# Cassandra cluster deployment scenario with Kaa Cluster

Tags: cassandra, kaa

I was surveying middleware to build a home automation, and I came across Kaa.

I noticed that one of Kaa supported NoSQL database option is Cassandra, and I would like to understand more about its deployment scenario in cluster mode.

1. I followed the installation guide on [official link](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Installation+guide#Installationguide-Firewallrulesconfiguration) to build a
   standalone Kaa node with a Cassandra installed on the same node.
   However, my question would be that is there a way to have a external
   Cassandra cluster served as a separate storage node? I do not see
   there is an option in etc configuration file.
2. What is the default RF for storing large amount of endpoints, and
   what is the CL for read / write operation if using Cassandra as
   storage engine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can configure Cassandra cluster on separate nodes, use new [Cluster-setup](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Administration-guide/System-installation/Cluster-setup/) documentation for details.
2. RF and CL value you can choose based on Cassandra documentation. For example [Data distribution and replication](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/architecture/archDataDistributeAbout.html).

Comment: Got it! Seems all those parameter is configurable in /etc/kaa-node/conf/common-dao-cassandra.properties, as specified in the doc you provided above. Thanks!